# python regex search in complex pattern

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I'm new about python.

It is hard time to me.

Now I'm finding some strings in files.

I had regex but I don't know how to use it in python. It works in Eclipse.

below one is the regex.

```
("|')\w+\1\s*=\s*?\w*?\.?suppkdid
```

this is my source I tried.

```
import fnmatch, re, os

regex =  ''  #Q1. How could it be possible? 

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('C:\the_file_directory'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.odi'):
        with open(os.path.join(root, filename)) as f:
            for line in f:
                                if regex.search(line) is not None: #Q2. Is it right?
                                    print '=========================='
                                    print 'filename : %s' %filename 
                                    print 'line : %s' %line
                                    print '=========================='
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
regex=re.compile(r"""("|')\w+\1\s*=\s*?\w*?\.?suppkdid""")
```

You need create a regex compiled pattern.

In fact you can directly use

```
if re.search(r"""("|')\w+\1\s*=\s*?\w*?\.?suppkdid""",line) is not None:
```

Also use

```
"""
```

instead of `"` or `'` as they both are in your pattern.

Comment: Ookay, I'll try new one.

Comment: I need little more, how can I this regex case insensitive?

Comment: @lv0gun9 just add `flag=re.Ignorecase`